# Resuing HTML IFS file in Iseries

Tags: cgi, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am a using webpage with  method. In the html form i have used POST method which is calling an RPGLE program and by using CGI libraries i am retrieving the values in my RPGLE program. Once i retrieve the value in program i want to show the same page again but after removing the entered value on the form page.
I am trying to use getHtmlIfs() location method to read the same IFS file and then using wrtsection('*fini') as i haven't specified any tag in html. but it is giving me internal server error.
i tried to use tag and write it as well but still the same result.

please advise.

Comment: This could be a good question. What you need to do is provide a small, sample code that exhibits your issue, then tell us the specific error codes you are getting, if any, and the input you are using, and the output you are getting. Make sure you put enough code there that a person could cut and paste it onto their system and compile and run it. As it is , we can guess what the problem is, but that is about all.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the CGIDEV2 package.

1. You say you write *fini, but are you writing an actual record first?
2. Check the joblog for the CGI job (they run in QHTTPSVR subsystem by default).
3. Check the CGIDEBUG table in your CGI library.

Comment: gethtmlifs(<ifslocation>) and then write(*fini);                    i didn't put that tag in HTML definition tag like we normally do - <ibmi>(or anything) which can tell HTML that it's header / body /footer. I didn't put it because page wasn't showing anything it was only taking value from users and then call backend program based on method...so as a workaround, i have created similar HTML page with tags in it and then loaded that it worked. can't we load the page from AS400 without tag.. if it's simple page.. error in job log - End of script output before headers:

Comment: You said "I didn't put it because page wasn't showing anything".  If this is a simple URL from the browser, you'll need to return something (even an empty page).